# How to use Ctrl+C to stop whole script not just current command

Tags: bash, ctrl

I have a script such as follows:

```
for ((i=0; i < $srccount; i++)); do
    echo -e "\"${src[$i]}\" will be synchronized to \"${dest[$i]}\""
    echo -e $'Press any key to continue or Ctrl+C to exit...\n' 
    read -rs -n1
    rsync ${opt1} ${opt2} ${opt3} ${src[$i]} ${dest[$i]}
done
```

If I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> in response to read command, the whole script will stop, but if press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> while `rsync` command is running, just current `rsync` command will stop and the script will continue the for loop.

Is there any way to tell the script if the user pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> while `rsync` is running, stop `rsync` and exit from the script itself?

Comment: `opt1`, `opt2`, `opt3`, `srccount`, `src` and `dest`are defined in the previous line of the script.

Comment: `trap "exit" INT`. See http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/48432/50240

Answer (score 60, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> sends the interrupt signal, `SIGINT`. You need to tell bash to exit when it receives this signal, via the `trap` built-in:

```
trap "exit" INT
for ((i=0; i < $srccount; i++)); do
    echo -e "\"${src[$i]}\" will be synchronized to \"${dest[$i]}\""
    echo -e $'Press any key to continue or Ctrl+C to exit...\n' 
    read -rs -n1
    rsync ${opt1} ${opt2} ${opt3} ${src[$i]} ${dest[$i]}
done
```

You can do more than just exiting upon receiving a signal.  Commonly, signal handlers remove temporary files.  Refer to the [bash documentation](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/chap_12.html) for more details.

Comment: Be aware that this will not work if script is launched using "source": `. script.sh`

Comment: I recommend `trap "echo; exit" INT` to make sure your next shell prompt is on a clean line

Comment: trap "echo; exit" INT not returning to command input mode

Comment: @AravindVemula perhaps bash is still waiting for the command to finish? In the documentation linked in my answer note this: "When Bash receives a signal for which a trap has been set while waiting for a command to complete, the trap will not be executed until the command completes." If that is not it, feel free to post a new question.

Comment: @bishop your solution worked like a charm man, I was talking about one in the comment cheers 

Answer (score -14):

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>. It will stop your script entirely.

Comment: No, ctrl + z will only suspend the process.  It will still be there and can be resumed by typing `fg`.

Comment: Not working as you say.