# how to break from a while loop that reads a file in bash

Tags: bash, while-loop, break

I was trying to break a loop I created with
ctrl+C while reading a file.
Instead it was just stopping the specific iteration and not
the whole loop.
How can I stop it completely instead of having to ctrl+C all the iterations?
The whole script can be found [here](https://github.com/ConYel/various_scripts/blob/master/download_SRA.sh)

An example file is like that:

```
echo -e "SRR7637893\nSRR7637894\nSRR7637895\nSRR7637896" > filenames.txt
```

The specific code chunk that probably makes the issue is the while loop here(set -xv; has been added afterwards as suggested from markp-fuso in comments):

```
set -xv;
while read -r line; do
 echo "Now downloading "${line}"\n"
 docker run --rm -v "$OUTPUT_DIR":/data -w /data inutano/sra-toolkit:v2.9.2 fasterq-dump "${line}" -t /data/shm -e $PROCESSORS
 if [[ -s $OUTPUT_DIR/${line}.fastq ]]; then
 echo "Using pigz on ${line}.fastq" 
     pigz --best $OUTPUT_DIR/"${line}*.fastq"
 else 
    echo "$OUTPUT_DIR/${line}.fastq not found"
 fi
 done < "$INPUT_txt"; set +xv
```

Comment: Not completely clear (to me) what you're trying to do. Do you know there is a `break` keyword you could add anywhere inside a looping structure to stop the processing of the loop? If you are having trouble using that, your Q should include the tested `break` code AND a small set of sample input and expected output/actions. Good luck.

Comment: No I haven't used break yet, I saw that the code didn't worked for one of the filenames and I tried to stop it with CTRL+C but instead of stopping it just move to the next iteration. So it read the next line (which has a name of the next file to download etc)

Comment: Better to fix the code so valid filenames don't fail. Proably all you need is `pigz ... .../"$line"`. The Ctrl-C kills the current process, (something to do with `pigz ...` (probably)), so you need to do another Ctrl-C real fast to break the parent script. So try doing a bunch of Ctrl-Cs as fast as you can and it may stop the script. Good luck.

Comment: `echo "downloading the files ...processors` is missing a trailing double quote (`"`); is that a typo from cutting/pasting into the question? or are you really missing the trailing `"` in your script?; it would help to know where in the script the hanging is occurring ... during the `docker` call? during the `pigz` call? elsewhere? (try `set -xv; while ... done < "$INPUT_txt"; set +xv` to enable debugging while the code is running)

Comment: @shellter ok so the problem is the pigz?
My issue is let's say I have a file with 1000 file names, and each file takes at least 1 min to download plus could be large (1-2Gbytes). So, I would like for the script to always stop with CTRL+C in order to be sure that If something goes wrong with the files etc it will stop.

markp-fuso
yes it's a typo from copy/pasting sorry

Comment: Good advice from @markp-fuso (as usual). No, pigz is probably working fine, it's much more likely that there is something wrong with the value of the `$line` variable, AND the usual issue is that the filename has a space in it, OR less likely but possibl, `#!@#$%^&*()` all of which have special meaning to the shell, unless they are inside dbl-quote, hence `pigz ... .../"$line"`. (note that `$line` is now surrounded by dbl-quotes.) Good luck.

Comment: it might also help to add a test, `if [[ -f "$line" ]] : then do pigz stuff ; else echo "error : no file named $line" >&2 ; fi`. Good luck.

Comment: Also, you'll do well to read, review and take to heart the items on this page : https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info . Search for "Before asking about Problematic code" and "How to turn a bad script into a good question" . That is to say, don't focus on "i've got thousands of lines", give us the value for one `$line` that is failing. (Please UPDATE YOUR Q, don't reply in comments for this) . Good luck.

Comment: @shellter Just to make things clear my issue was not about the $line argument but if I want to stop completely the script with CRTL+C it didn't. I tried again now with doing it many times in the same second and it seem it worked. But my question is, if there is a way to make something like a bubble to put the while loop reading the file so if I CTRL+C it stops completely. Sorry if I didn't ask clearly in the first place.

Comment: I see we got distracted and confused (-; . Try `wrapping the whole thing in a sub-shell, like `( while .... done < file )` . You may need to add `"\"` character (no dbl-quotes needed, no trailing white space chars allowed) at the end of each line of your multiline while loop. Good luck.

Comment: If you suspect docker to not propagate the SIGINT signal, you can try replacing `docker ...` with `docker ... & trap "kill -SIGINT $! " SIGINT; wait $! ; trap - SIGINT` (not 100% sure it will solve your problem but I guess it should grab more signals)

Comment: This answers the SO's question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32145643/how-to-use-ctrlc-to-stop-whole-script-not-just-current-command